# Сколько компьютеров и мониторов должно быть у эффективного разработчика?

Tags: работа

Как количество компьютеров и мониторов (укомплектованность рабочего места) влияет на производительность труда программиста?

Comment: @Dmitri N Уважаемый участник, мы изменили форму и нацеленность Вашего вопроса, чтобы он не был темой-опросом и в большей степени соответствовал формату форума.

Comment: Ну ладно, я не против :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле на эту проблему можно посмотреть по-разному.

1. Во-первых часто наши программисты элементарно не знают даже основных комбинаций клавиш. Ибо если работаешь на небольшом мониторе (а это иногда может быть определено условиями, в которых приходится работать). Мне, например, четыре дня в неделю приходится работать по два с половиной часа в поезде, естественно это неудобно, т.к. разрешение экрана 1280 на 800, при этом я уже привык работать с Eclipse за 7 месяцев.
2. Во-вторых глупо брать, лишь бы взять. Всегда в т.ч. и у программиста в голове должны быть всегда "весы" между ценой и оптимальностью (в различных вариациях).
3. В-третьих. Собственно отрицать, что большой монитор это бесспорно лучше я не буду. Но стоит говорить не только о мониторах. Т.к. я работаю постоянно с серверами, мне просто необходима клавиатура нормальная (ну нету у меня на ноутбуке цифровой панели, которая так необходима, чтобы быстро набрать какой-то IP-адрес). В конце концов нужно куча места на рабочем столе, чтобы расположить все бумажки, все устройства (перманентно использую 8 различных периферийных устройств).

Всегда нужно искать компромисс: занимаемое место; время переключения; время, которое затрачивается на всякую мелочь; цена; производительность и т.д.

Имхо, для программиста одна из самых основных задач - оптимизация.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый комментарий. 8 периферийных устройств - интересно каких! Лично у меня доходит только до дополнительных USB-карточек и флешек/токенов в них воткнутых.

Comment: Дело в том, что основную рабочую информацию храню на внешнем диске (там объем больше), при этом чтобы скорость доступа была выше работаю исключительно с внутренним диском (внешний бекапит инфу периодически на всякий случай, уж больно все важно).
Кроме этого осваиваюсь с Андроидом, поэтому телефон также постоянно включен.
Принтер, сканер - незаменимые вещи, поэтому даже не обсуждается.
Веб-камера также вещь незаменимая (к сожалению не имею встроенной).
Мышь и клавиатура, как уже говорил, не могу пользоваться клавиатурой ноутбука.

Comment: Конечно, я, наверное, погорячился, что написал "перманентно" на самом деле, если смотреть в промежутке = 1 суток. Так как еще использую ИК-порт для управления плеером и др. функциями (специально сделан на заказ для меня, со специальными функциями).
Кроме того, периодически появляются флешки, камера, электронные ключи и т.п. В итоге много проводов, дополнительный хаб с независимым от USB питанием (к сожалению, три года назад еще не было ноутов с USB3.0). Вот собственно и рабочее место, на котором осталось пара незанятых квадратных сантиметров.

Comment: Пересев с десктопа на ноутбук, я оценил качество клавиатур ноутбуков фирмы IBM. Хоть и нет доп. цифровой клавиатуры, но я быстро адаптировался цифры набирать стандартным горизонтальным рядом.
А вообще выбор клавы действительно отдельная тема.
PS: на десктопе использую старую добрую механическую клавиатуру IBM made by Lexmark 1983-го.

Comment: Насчет клавиатур - интересно, я сам сижу на 20-долларов Microsoft Comfort Curve хотя иногда тянет купить что-нибуль поинтересней. Другая переферия тоже конечно есть, я просто думал у вас какие-нибудь девайсы заумные, мне интересно.

Про повальное использование RDP и виртуалок я как бы знаю, а еще активно использую Synergy+DropBox для того чтобы на несколько экранов проецировать изображения с разных компов и управлять ими одной клавиатурой и мышью.

Comment: Да в общем-то много факторов играет роль на производительность труда программиста. Но одно можно сказать точно, у каждого укомплектованность рабочего стола разная, кому как удобнее.
Что касается клавиатур, я был расстроен от того, что моя первая клавиатура сломалась, и обежал весь город в поисках такой же, но, к сожалению, не нашел. А самое классное в той клавиатуре было для меня, как начинающего программиста - это "быстрые" клавиши "Копировать", "Вырезать", "Вставить". Я настолько к ним привык, что скорость иногда возрастала капитально.

Comment: Ну да, я тоже склонен думать, что рабочее место нужно организовывать в индивидульном порядке, и что подвести всех под одну гребенку не лучшая идея.

Answer (score 3):

У меня вообще только нетбук. :) Но, конечно, я бы не отказался от нескольких мониторов.

Answer (score 2):

Общеизвестно, что чем больше монитор, тем выше эффективность программиста. Можно также добавить второй монитор, что тоже полезно. Минимальный расклад, чтобы действительно не ощущать стеснения: либо два по 17", либо один 22". (У меня, например, 17"+22").

Компьютера обычно достаточно одного, если не требуется запускать что-то особое в особых условиях (например, под чужеродной ОС). В таких случаях, не всегда удобно мучаться с виртуальными машинами, а иногда это просто напросто неудовлетворительно. Дополнительные тачки могут быть полезны для автоматического тестирования и для выполнения сборок. Но обычно это просто выделенные сервера, а не личные машины разработчиков.

Comment: А не напрягает, что мониторы разного размера?

Comment: Нет, нисколько. Второй, который меньше идёт как вспомогательный. Например, во время отладки очень удобно открывать там окно Watches

Comment: Я лично сижу на ноуте с UXGA разрешением - 1600x1200. И мне хватает. Чем больше разрешение - тем больше рабочая область. Коллеги очень радуются широкоформатным мониторам с высоким разрешением (1920x1200, что всяко больше, чем HD), т.к. это позволяет им эффективно разложить окна и панельки.
Второй монитор так же удобен. В быту, супруга на одном странички открывает в одном браузере, а на другом - в другом браузере+музыкальный плейер+качалка+всякая мелочь. По работе - удобно вытащить на второй монитор виртуальную машину или окно отладчика.

Comment: По личным наблюдениям могу сказать что на 24", разрешение 1920x1200 выглядит просто безобразно, даже на дорогом Dell за RUR25k :)

Answer (score 1):

Если есть несколько мониторов, то лучше подобрать с одинаковым вертикальным количеством пикселей. В противном случае всё, конечно, работает, но есть кое-какие неудобства. (У моего десктопа 20''+15''). Но как-то недавно работал с ноутом 17'' с дополнительным 24''. Очень здорово! Много окон помещается! Скорость разработки явно увеличивается. Если есть возможность, не экономьте на мониторе.
По поводу компьютеров (имхо): десктоп для основной работы и ноут + какой-нибудь мобильный интернет для работы в любом месте.

Comment: (Имхо) 24" это чуток многовато. Для фильмов в 1080p безусловно хорошо, но кода на таком мониторе многовато, а если в 2 колонки делать - маловато.

Answer (score 1):

Сколько угодно. Все зависит от того чего вы хотите от рабочего места и какой бюджет есть.
Если кодер то я бы выбрал 2 моника Samsung SyncMaster BX2440 и поставил бы их вертикально (подставка позволяет). Таким образом можно разместить на один моник много кода, а второй забить еще чем то полезным.

Comment: А вот вертикально ставить не всем пойдет. Я использую Windows, а в нем - ClearType, который становится более-менее бессмысленным если монитор перевернуть.

Comment: Ну так не используйте.

Comment: ClearType отключать?! Увы, это невозможно, у нас не 200lpi мониторы, каждый пиксель играет роль, и работать под VS без ClearType... ну я себе это просто представить не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Физически один, виртуальных множество. Это виртуальные машины типо вари.

Comment: Один, но очень широкий. Чтобы много исходников подряд править можно было.1

Comment: Это для java программистов надо мониторы по шире, а для си программеров хватит и 19".

Comment: Я с вами не согласен: при написании С-кода экран побольше точно не будет лишним ;)

Answer (score 1):

Я программирую исключительно на нетбуке с 10-дюймовым дисплеем. Как-то привык уже, успеваю все проекты в срок сдавать.

Comment: А как же отладка итп? Как минимум 2й монитор имхо должен быть чтобы иметь одно окно для бебаггера и другое для того что дебажишь.

Comment: Я занимаюсь исключительно программированием скриптов, результаты смотрю в браузере, между ним и редактором переключаюсь альт-табом. Ничего сложного, только прокручивать по вертикали в отличие от обычного монитора приходится больше из-за расширения дисплея 1024 на 600

Comment: Да, и кстати, за что меня минусовали? По вашему ответ не по теме был? На мой взгляд мне совершенно необоснованно поставили минус. Каждый по-своему организовывает свое рабочее место, разве не так? Поначалу к хэшкоду я относился к энтузиазмом, но со временем он все меньше мне нравится. Админы просто зациклены на корректности и "правильности" ответов...

Comment: Ну, я тут только плюсую. Но админы делают все правильно, ибо если дать кому-нибудь на этапе становления ресурса его замусорить, то может и не "взлететь".

Answer (score 0):

Мне всегда хватало одного нормального компьютера и монитора. А то, что чем больше мониторов и компьютеров, тем больше эффективность, сие сказки. Эффективность программиста зависит только и только от его личных качеств (ну, конечно, без экстремальных вариантов). Наши отцы ваще в уме и на бумажке программировали.

Comment: Да, но научные исследования и личный опыт показывают обратное: лишний монитор повышает эффективность.